# How to get all the device information between two devices

Tags: switch, ipv4, mac-address, ping

I've two devices: **My-PC** and **Another-PC**.

The two devices are connected to a switch, which is connected to main switch with-in the same `LAN`.

My question is: how do I get all the device information such as (IP address, MAC address, Serial Number) from **My-PC** to **Another-PC**?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The destination gets the layer-2 (e.g. MAC), layer-3 (e.g. IP), and layer-4 (e.g. TCP) addresses from the source when something is sent from one to the other. Other information, e.g. serial number, has nothing to do with the network, is OS specific (off-topic), and it would need to be handled by a protocol above OSI layer-4 (off-topic).

The frame sent from one to the other has both the source and destination MAC addresses (assuming it is a layer-2 protocol that uses MAC addresses, e.g. ethernet) in the frame header. This only works if both the source and destination are on the same layer-2 LAN.

An IP packet in that frame will have both the source and destination IP addresses in the packet header.

A TCP segment or UDP datagram will contain both the source and destination addresses (ports) in its header.

The addressing will be part of what is sent, but other information, e.g. the serial number, will be OS specific (off-topic) and require an application (off-topic) or protocols above OSI layer-4 (off-topic).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,, but i need MAC address and IP address for the switches which the packet send from source to destination throw it,,, is this information stored in packet ???

Comment: Switches are transparent devices, and they do not alter the original frames. In fact, unmanaged switches do not have IP or MAC addresses. Managed switches do, but that is only for the management of the switch, which is a host on the LAN, and plays no part in the actual switching of the frames on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

This is the information you can extract from devices connected by a switch in a simple way:

- IP address: just ping all possible, local IP addresses and look at the local ARP cache right after each attempt you'll find an entry for any IP address present (the ARP lookup also turns up devices not honoring ICMP echo requests)
- MAC address: see above - the MAC address will be in the ARP cache, associated with the IP address
- the first three octets (bytes) of the MAC address reveal the vendor of the device (or the NIC)

Additionally, you could e.g. examine LLDP packets or STP BPDUs to find out more about the infrastructure but you don't seem to be looking for that.